# Split CSV into two files based on column matching values in an array in bash / posh

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I have a input CSV that I would like to split into two CSV files. If the value of column 4 matches any value in WLTarray it should go in output file 1, if it doesn't it should go in output file 2.

WLTarray:

```
"22532" "79994" "18809" "21032"
```

input CSV file:

```
header1,header2,header3,header4,header5,header6,header7,header8
"83","6344324","585677","22532","Entitlements","BX","22532:718","36721"
"83","1223432","616454","79994","Compliance Stuff","DR","79994:64703","206134"
"83","162217","616454","83223","Data Enrichment","IEO","83223:64701","206475"
"83","267216","616457","79994","Compliance Engine","ABC","79994:64703","206020"
```

output CSV file1:

```
header1,header2,header3,header4,header5,header6,header7,header8
"83","6344324","585677","22532","Entitlements","BX","22532:718","36721"
"83","1223432","616454","79994","Compliance Stuff","DR","79994:64703","206134"
"83","267216","616457","79994","Compliance Engine","ABC","79994:64703","206020"
```

output CSV file2:

```
header1,header2,header3,header4,header5,header6,header7,header8
"83","162217","616454","83223","Data Enrichment","IEO","83223:64701","206475"
```

I've been looking at awk to filter this (python & perl not an option in my environment) but I think there is probably a much smarter way:

```
  declare -a WLTarray=("22532" "79994" "18809" "21032")
  for WLTvalue in "${WLTarray[@]}" #Everything in the WLTarray will go to $filename-WLT.tmp
  do
        awk -F, '($4=='$WLTvalue'){print}' $filename.tmp >> $filename-WLT.tmp #move the lines to the WLT file
        # now filter to remove non matching values? why not just move the rows entirely?        
  done
```

Answer (score 1):

With regular `awk` you can make use of `split` and `substr` (to handle double-quote removal for comparison) and split the csv file as you indicate. For example you can use:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; s="22532 79994 18809 21032"
        split (s,a," ")     # split s into array a
        for (i in a)        # loop over each index in a
            b[a[i]]=1       # use value in a as index for b
    }
    FNR == 1 {      # first record, write header to both output files
        print $0 > "output1.csv"
        print $0 > "output2.csv"
        next
    }
    substr($4,2,length($4)-2) in b {    # 4th field w/o quotes in b?
        print $0 > "output1.csv"        # write to output1.csv
        next
    }
    { print $0 > "output2.csv" }        # otherwise write to output2.csv
' input.csv
```

Where:

- in the `BEGIN {...}` rule you set the *field separator* (`FS`) to break on comma, and split the string containing your desired `output1.csv` *field 4* matches into the array `a`, then loops over the values in `a` using them for the indexes in array `b` (to allow a simple `i in b` check);
- the first rule is applied to the first records in the file (the header line) which is simply written out to both output files;
- the next rule removes the double-quotes surrounding field-4 and then checks if the number in field-4 matches an index in array `b`. If so the record is written to `output1.csv` otherwise it is written to `output2.csv`.

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat input.csv
header1,header2,header3,header4,header5,header6,header7,header8
"83","6344324","585677","22532","Entitlements","BX","22532:718","36721"
"83","1223432","616454","79994","Compliance Stuff","DR","79994:64703","206134"
"83","162217","616454","83223","Data Enrichment","IEO","83223:64701","206475"
"83","267216","616457","79994","Compliance Engine","ABC","79994:64703","206020"
```

**Resulting Output Files**

```
$ cat output1.csv
header1,header2,header3,header4,header5,header6,header7,header8
"83","6344324","585677","22532","Entitlements","BX","22532:718","36721"
"83","1223432","616454","79994","Compliance Stuff","DR","79994:64703","206134"
"83","267216","616457","79994","Compliance Engine","ABC","79994:64703","206020"

$ cat output2.csv
header1,header2,header3,header4,header5,header6,header7,header8
"83","162217","616454","83223","Data Enrichment","IEO","83223:64701","206475"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gawk` like this:

*test.awk*

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN {
    split("22532 79994 18809 21032", a)
    for(i in a) {
        WLTarray[a[i]]
    }
    FPAT="[^\",]+"
}

NR > 1 {
    if ($4 in WLTarray) {
        print >> "output1.csv"
    } else {
        print >> "output2.csv"
    }
}
```

Make it executable and run it like this:

```
chmod +x test.awk
./test.awk input.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

using grep with a filter file as input was the simplest answer.

```
declare -a WLTarray=("22532" "79994" "18809" "21032")
        for WLTvalue in "${WLTarray[@]}" 
        do
            awkstring="'\$4 == "\"\\\"$WLTvalue\\\"\"" {print}'"
            eval "awk -F, $awkstring input.csv >> output.WLT.csv"
        done
        grep -v -x -f output.WLT.csv input.csv > output.NonWLT.csv
```